# Docker run immediately gets terminated while it should take around 5 min

Tags: python, docker

On my AWS EC2 instance(ubuntu), I pulled a docker container from my docker hub which I built on top of Python3.8 image. But the `docker run` command does not look like doing the job I defined in `Dockerfile`. Could anybody please take a look and provide me with some advices?

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "-u", "./main.py" ]
```

And here is my minimum reproducible main.py. It calls some modules, scrapes tweets, applies some NLP, and stores the results in the PostgreSQL database in an RDS instance in the same VPC.

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_batch
from search_tweets_v2 import search_tweets_v2
from clean_text import clean_text
from transformers import pipeline, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, BertJapaneseTokenizer, BertTokenizer

# connecting to Postgres database
params = "host=%s port=%i dbname=%s user=%s password=%s" % (HOST, PORT, DATABASE_NAME, DB_USER, PASSWORD)

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('daigo/bert-base-japanese-sentiment')
tokenizer = BertJapaneseTokenizer.from_pretrained('cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-whole-word-masking')
nlp = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, )

def main():

    for politician in ["Donald Trump", "Barack Obama"]:

        # search tweets and users
        original_tweets_list = search_tweets_v2(politician=politician.strip(), results_per_call=10, end_time="2022-01-07", max_results=5, max_pages=1)

        original_tweets_list_columns = list(original_tweets_list[0].keys())
        tweet_data = [
            tuple(tweet[column] for column in original_tweets_list_columns)
            for tweet in original_tweets_list
        ]
        tweet_data = [
            i + (clean_text(i[3]),) for i in tweet_data
        ]

        # append sentiment analysis
        tweet_data = [
            i + tuple(nlp(tweet_data[0][-1])[0].values()) for i in tweet_data
        ]

        conn = None
        try:
            # connect to the PostgreSQL database
            conn = psycopg2.connect(params)
            # create a new cursor
            cur = conn.cursor()
            full_query = "INSERT INTO tweets_processed VALUES (%s, %s, %s)ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT tweets_processed_pkey DO NOTHING"
            execute_batch(cur, full_query, tweet_data)

            # commit the changes to the database
            conn.commit()
            # close communication with the database
            cur.close()
        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(error)

        finally:
            if conn is not None:
                conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run `sudo docker run -p 5000:5000 my-image:test-0.0.4`, the container gets terminated in a second. It looks like it's not running `python3 ./main.py`, since it normally takes around 5 minutes to run it. In addition to that, I don't see any new data stored in my database, which also confirms that the docker container isn't working properly.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-:~$ sudo docker run -p 5000:5000 my-image:test-0.0.4
ubuntu@ip-172-:~$
```

`sudo docker ps -a` shows this:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-:~$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND        CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS      NAMES
cf4178e8b356   my-image:test-0.0.4   "bash"         2 minutes ago    Exited (0) 2 minutes ago               lucid_proskuriakova
```

`sudo docker logs` does not display anything.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-:~$ sudo docker logs cf4178e8b356
ubuntu@ip-172-:~$
```

Is the cause a connection problem to the RDS instance? I doubt that, because I can enter the container's bash, and manually run `python3 ./main.py` and it works without any issues. From the container's bash, I can also talk to the databse with `psql` command.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-:~$ sudo docker run -it -p 5000:5000 my-image:test-0.0.4 bash
root@73464edb3c12:/usr/src/app# psql --host=database-2.cb3rw2aaswqwk.eu-west-3.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=postgres --password --dbname=my_webapp_db
Password:
psql (13.5 (Debian 13.5-0+deb11u1), server 13.3)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

my_webapp_db=>
```

Comment: Is this behaviour specific to AWS? What happens locally?

Comment: BTW: You can retrieve the logs of a terminated container!

Comment: thanks for your comment. I'm checking in my local environment... Meanwhile, I edited the question with the result of `sudo docker logs`. It doesn't show anything(there's no logs).

Comment: In my local environment, it behaves exactly the same way as on EC2. No logs, no output.

Comment: What is your main.py? The issue has nothing to do with AWS.

Comment: my main.py imports `psycopg2` and `transformers`, scrapes tweets using twitter API and applies some NLP, and then stores the results in postgres database on another EC2 in the same VPC. the whole of this works when I get in the container and run manually `python3 ./main.py`

Comment: Something in the script is exiting (successfully, with status code 0) immediately when you run it in a container (maybe without a stdin).  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]; not your whole application, but enough running Python code that works interactively but not in a container?

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks, I added the main.py in the question.

Comment: Where is the database?  It will not be `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` in this context.  If it's something like an RDS instance it should still work fine, but if there's a connection problem you could get the "exited (0)".  Even so, it wouldn't be different running interactively and you should see the `print()`ed error message.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes my database is in an RDS instance in the same VPC. I doubt there's a connection problem because, from the container's bash, I can talk to this database with `psql` command, as well as in python with `psycopg2` module. The only time that it doesn't work is when I do `docker run`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python script successfully runs to completion - `Exited (0)`. There's nothing else for the container to do, so it stops. Unclear why you expect different. The behavior is no different than running your script outside of Docker, a process starts and exits.

> Strangely, I can enter the container... and it works without any issues

This isn't strange. You're entering an interactive shell, which remains open. The script itself still exits with code 0

Comment: It is strange, because running `python3 main.py` should take around 5 min, whereas the container stops immediately. In addition to that, after running `docker run`, I don't see any new data stored in my database, which also confirms that the docker container isn't working properly.

Comment: If there's no exceptions, add print statements to your code for logging its actions. Otherwise, one problem I see is that you want `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD` in your dockerfile